# How to get XmlElement name in list of XmlElements

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, xml-binding

I am getting XML from a REST service that looks like:

```
<entity>
  <foo>
    <count>1</count>
    <date>1970-01-01</date>
    <margin>78.67</margin>
  </foo>
  <bar>
    <count>2</count>
    <date>1450-09-17</date>
    <margin>24.56</margin>
  </bar>
  <baz>
    <count>11</count>
    <date>1968-11-12</date>
    <margin>98.76</margin>
  </baz>
</entity>
```

And I'm parsing with a class Entity.java that has:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "entity")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Entity implements Serializable {

  @XmlElements({
        @XmlElement(name="foo"),
        @XmlElement(name="bar"),
        @XmlElement(name="baz")
  })
  private List<EntityElement> entityElements;
....
```

With an EntityElement class like:

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class EntityElement implements Serializable {
    @XmlElement(required = true)
    private int count

    @XmlElement(required = true)
    private String date;

    @XmlElement(required = false)
    private long margin;
....
```

This all works exactly like I expect and I get a list of EntityElements. What I would like to do is add a name field and have it populated with the name of the element that was found (a foo, bar, or baz) but I'm not seeing any way to do this. Any help or suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Why not simply have 3 fields foo, bar and baz in your entity? That way, you would know which is null and which is not.

Comment: This should help: http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/08/removing-jaxbelement-from-your-domain.html

Answer (score 2):

**Note:**  I'm the [**EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)**](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) lead and a member of the [**JAXB (JSR-222)**](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) expert group.

You could use the `@XmlVariableNode` that we added to MOXy in EclipseLink 2.5.1 for this use case.

### Java Model

**Entity**

We will use MOXy's `@XmlVariableNode` on the `entityElements` field.  On the field we specify the field on the target class that represents the element name.

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;
import org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.annotations.XmlVariableNode;

@XmlRootElement(name = "entity")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Entity implements Serializable {

    @XmlVariableNode("name")
    private List<EntityElement> entityElements;

}
```

**EntityElement**

We will use the `@XmlTransient` annotation to prevent the value of the `name` field from being marshalled as a child element.

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class EntityElement implements Serializable {

    @XmlTransient
    private String name;

    @XmlElement(required = true)
    private int count;

    @XmlElement(required = true)
    private String date;

    @XmlElement(required = false)
    private long margin;

}
```

**jaxb.properties**

To specify MOXy as your JAXB provider you need to include a file called `jaxb.properties` in the same package as your domain model with the following entry (see:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/05/specifying-eclipselink-moxy-as-your.html).

```
javax.xml.bind.context.factory=org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory
```

### Demo Code

**Demo**

Since MOXy is a JAXB (JSR-222) implementation only the standard runtime APIs are required.

```
import java.io.File;
import javax.xml.bind.*;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Entity.class);

        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        File xml = new File("src/forum19194567/input.xml");
        Entity entity = (Entity) unmarshaller.unmarshal(xml);

        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.marshal(entity, System.out);
    }

}
```

**input.xml/Output**

This is the XML document from your question.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<entity>
   <foo>
      <count>1</count>
      <date>1970-01-01</date>
      <margin>0</margin>
   </foo>
   <bar>
      <count>2</count>
      <date>1450-09-17</date>
      <margin>0</margin>
   </bar>
   <baz>
      <count>11</count>
      <date>1968-11-12</date>
      <margin>0</margin>
   </baz>
</entity>
```

### For More Information

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/search/label/XmlVariableNode